# Is there a way to assert current URL value in Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

I'm testing a web application with subdomain routing with Laravel Dusk. I have some redirection between subdomain, if some kind of verification is invalid.

So, my goal is to `visit` an URL `$a` then assert that I was redirected and the new URL is `$b`.

I can do:

```
$browser->visit($a);
```

But I don't know what to do right after to check what the current URL is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a way to check the URL value in Laravel Dusk:

```
$browser->visit($a);
$url = $browser->driver->getCurrentURL();
$this->assertEquals($b, $url);
```

Comment: +1. `$browser->driver->getCurrentURL()` was helpful for me when using `waitUsing` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#waiting-for-elements)

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: The most convenient is `assertPathIs()`

A) Use `assertPathIs()` to assert that the current relative path matches the given path.

```
$browser->visit('/admin')
  ->assertPathIs('/login');
```

B) Use `assertUrlIs()` to assert that the current URL matches the given URL.

```
$browser->visit('/admin')
  ->assertUrlIs('http://fullhost.com/login');
```

Note that you must provide a full URL for this one. Use it when you have URLs with external domains.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `assertUrlIs()`:

```
$browser->assertUrlIs($b);
```